# Displaying symbols when scraping a website using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, symbols

I'm new to web scraping. I was trying to solve an issue regarding how symbols are displayed. BeautifulSoup is used to scrape the website but there's an issue with how symbols are scraped.

This is the working code:

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(message['content'], 'lxml') 
content = (None, soup2markup(soup.find(name='body')))

def soup2markup(self, soup: Any) -> List[Any]:
    for element in soup:
        if (element.name == 'span' and element.attrs and
            ('katex-display' in element.attrs.get('class', []) or
             'katex' in element.attrs.get('class', []))):
            markup.append(element.text)
    return markup
```

Printing `markup`, i.e. displaying the scraped text for a symbol such as *π* (whose katex text is `$$\pi$$`), gives me

*π\piπ*

instead of just

*π*.

Why does this happen and how do I fix it?

```html
<div class="message_content rendered_markdown">
<p>
<span class="katex">
<span class="katex-mathml">
<math>
<semantics>
<mrow>
<mi>π</mi>
</mrow>
<annotation encoding="application/x-tex">\pi</annotation>
</semantics>
</math>
</span>
<span aria-hidden="true" class="katex-html">
<span class="strut" style="height:0.43056em;">
</span>
<span class="strut bottom" style="height:0.43056em;vertical-align:0em;">
</span>
<span class="base">
<span class="mord mathit" style="margin-right:0.03588em;">π</span>
</span>
</span>
</span>
</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Not related to your problem, but I don't think those type annotations should be `Any`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reproduce your problem directly - your code doesn't work for me.  However given this span, `s`

```html
<span class="katex-mathml">
<math>
<semantics>
<mrow>
<mi>π</mi>
</mrow>
<annotation encoding="application/x-tex">\pi</annotation>
</semantics>
</math>
</span>
```

We can see that accessing its `text` attribute shows the problem:

```
>>> s.text
'\n\n\n\nπ\n\n\\pi\n\n\n'
>>> print(s.text.replace('\n', ''))
π\pi
```

So the solution is to apply more precise search criteria, for example:

```
>>> m = s.find(name='mi')
>>> m
<mi>π</mi>
>>> m.text
'π'
```